# Mysql Inner Join same table

Tags: mysql

Table structure for table `bp_hotel_items`

```
|id|hotel_id|area_id|item_id|price|
|4 |2       |2      |2      |50.00
|5 |2       |2      |3      |100.00
|6 |2       |2      |4      |100.00
|7 |2       |2      |5      |170.00
|10|2       |2      |6      |70.00
|29|1       |0      |2      |95.00
|30|1       |0      |3      |150.00
|31|1       |0      |4      |300.00
|32|1       |0      |5      |120.00
```

Above is the table and I used this query

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.item_id 
FROM bp_hotel_items a 
WHERE a.hotel_id IN (1,2 ) AND a.item_id NOT IN (2,3)"
```

expected output:

```
item_id
4
5
```

but I get this output instead:

```
item_id
4
5
6
```

Can anyone help me with the query so that I get output as excepted?

Comment: Why you do not expect `6` is is not in `(2,3)`

Comment: For clarity, please add an explanation of what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: You should have to use `NOT IN (2,3,6)`

Comment: actually item_id NOT IN ($itemArray); $itemArray is dynamic ajax page variable, then can we get my excepted result

Answer (score 3):

This query should give you the expected result:

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.item_id 
from bp_hotel_items a 
WHERE a.hotel_id IN (1,2 ) AND a.item_id NOT IN (2,3,6)
```

Comment: item_id NOT IN ($itemArray); $itemArray is dynamic ajax page variable, then can we get my excepted result